# In Intellij, how do I create a live template that adds import statements for tests?

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I'd like to be able to type `test` in a class file and then press tab and have that expand to:

```
@Test
public void whenThen() {

}
```

And also include appropriate imports.  This includes `import static junit.framework.Assert.*;`.

How do I do this?  I'm using Intellij 12

Comment: It should import the annotation already if you have automatic importing on.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can create a live template for `test` in IntelliJ 12 like so:

File > Settings... > Live Templates

[image: Adding a template]

1. Add a new template
2. Set the abbreviation (what you'll type to use this filter)
3. Type this template (after pressing tab, your cursor will be at $EXPR$ to finish the name of the method, in this case, and $END$ is where the cursor will be after completing the $EXPR$ name (i.e., pressing enter)

   ```
   @org.junit.Test
   public void test$EXPR$() {
       $END$
   }
   ```
4. Ensure Expand with is set to Tab (or whichever you prefer)
5. Ensure Shorten Fully Qualified names is enabled (that way `@org.junit.Test` in the template adds `import org.junit.Test;` to the top of the file and the method will have just `@Test`)
6. Set the Applicable to "in Java: declaration".

Edit: as tieTYT points out, the the `import static junit.framework.Assert.*` part can be satisfied by creating a new File Template:

[image: JUnit Test File Template]

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME}
{

}
```

The above is just copy-pasted from the Class template, adding the `import` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think I can add the static import as a file template maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Now its possible to add **live templates** with **static imports**:

> You have to check static import in Options

```java
@org.junit.Test
public void should$EXPR$when$CONDITION$() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(null, org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is(org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue())); 
}
```

[image]